# Creating datetime in pandas from year and julian day

Tags: python, datetime, pandas, dataframe, time-series

```
                  ad_name    adl_name  year  JD 
0  united_states_of_america  colorado  2000   1 
1  united_states_of_america  colorado  2000   2 
2  united_states_of_america  colorado  2000   3 
3  united_states_of_america  colorado  2000   4 
4  united_states_of_america  colorado  2000   5
```

how do I add a datetime column using the `year` and `JD`  (julian day) columns? I was trying to use:

`pd.to_datetime(df, format='%Y_%d')`, but that does not work

Comment: I am not sure if I understand `julian day`. Is it different as `day`?

Comment: julian day is day of year and goes from 1 to 365/366

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need add to `year` column `JD` converted [`to_timedelta`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_timedelta.html):

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df.year, format='%Y') + pd.to_timedelta(df.JD - 1, unit='d')
print (df)
                    ad_name  adl_name  year  JD       date
0  united_states_of_america  colorado  2000   1 2000-01-01
1  united_states_of_america  colorado  2000   2 2000-01-02
2  united_states_of_america  colorado  2000   3 2000-01-03
3  united_states_of_america  colorado  2000   4 2000-01-04
4  united_states_of_america  colorado  2000   5 2000-01-05
```

Sample with `JD=32` and `JD=366`:

```
print (df)
                    ad_name  adl_name  year   JD
0  united_states_of_america  colorado  2000   32
1  united_states_of_america  colorado  2000  366

df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df.year, format='%Y') + pd.to_timedelta(df.JD - 1, unit='d')
print (df)
                    ad_name  adl_name  year   JD       date
0  united_states_of_america  colorado  2000   32 2000-02-01
1  united_states_of_america  colorado  2000  366 2000-12-31
```

Comment: will it work for julian day going from 1 to 365 / 366 (leap year)?