# Convert Julian dates to normal dates in a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, dataframe

I have a  date column in a pandas DF with Julian dates. How can I convert these Julian dates to mm-dd-yyyy format.

**Sample data**

```
     ORG   CHAIN_NBR  SEQ_NBR     INT_STATUS  BLOCK_CODE_1  DATA_BLOCK_CODE_1
0   523         1        0          A             C             2012183
1   523         2        1          I             A             2013025
2   521         3        1          A             H             2007067
3   513         4        1          D             H             2001046
4   513         5        1          8             I             2006075
```

I was using `jd2gcal` function but it's not working. I was also trying to write a code like this but of no use.

```
for i,row in amna.iterrows():
    amna['DATE_BLOCK_CODE_1'] = datetime.datetime.strptime(row['DATE_BLOCK_CODE_1'], '%Y%j')
```

desired Output:

```
    ORG   CHAIN_NBR  SEQ_NBR     INT_STATUS  BLOCK_CODE_1  DATA_BLOCK_CODE_1
0   523         1        0          A             C             mm-dd-yyyy
1   523         2        1          I             A             mm-dd-yyyy
2   521         3        1          A             H             mm-dd-yyyy
3   513         4        1          D             H             mm-dd-yyyy
4   513         5        1          8             I             mm-dd-yyyy
```

Please help me with this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
julian = df.DATA_BLOCK_CODE_1.str[4:].str.extract("([1-9][0-9]?[0-9]?)")    
df["DATA_BLOCK_CODE_1"] = df.DATA_BLOCK_CODE_1.str[:4] + "-" + julian
df['DATA_BLOCK_CODE_1'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DATA_BLOCK_CODE_1'], format='%Y-%j')
```

[image]

The regular expression would require the digits to start any digit but 0. (I assume `DATA_BLOCK_CODE_1` is of string type.)

Answer (score 4):

Let's try something like this

```
df['New Date'] = (pd.to_datetime((df.DATA_BLOCK_CODE_1 // 1000).astype(str)) + 
                 pd.to_timedelta(df.DATA_BLOCK_CODE_1 % 1000, unit='D'))

print(df)

   ORG  CHAIN_NBR  SEQ_NBR INT_STATUS BLOCK_CODE_1  DATA_BLOCK_CODE_1   New Date
0  523          1        0          A            C            2012183 2012-07-02
1  523          2        1          I            A            2013025 2013-01-26
2  521          3        1          A            H            2007067 2007-03-09
3  513          4        1          D            H            2001046 2001-02-16
4  513          5        1          8            I            2006075 2006-03-17
```

Comment: You are faster again ;-)

Comment: @MaxU :)  Thanks.   I wonder if there was something more native to datetime than this.

Comment: @ScottBoston this works great  but I also have 0's in the DATA_BLOCK_CODE_1, if I have 0's then its not working.... How can I handle that, Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

The Pandas [to_datetime function](https://www.google.com/search?q=pandas%20to_datetime&oq=pandas%20to_datetime&aqs=chrome..69i57.4815j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) has an `origin` parameter for julian to datetime conversion:

```
amna['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(amna['DATA_BLOCK_CODE_1'], unit='D', origin='julian')

print(df)

   ORG  CHAIN_NBR  SEQ_NBR INT_STATUS BLOCK_CODE_1  DATA_BLOCK_CODE_1   Date
0  523          1        0          A            C            2012183 2012-07-02
1  523          2        1          I            A            2013025 2013-01-26
2  521          3        1          A            H            2007067 2007-03-09
3  513          4        1          D            H            2001046 2001-02-16
4  513          5        1          8            I            2006075 2006-03-17
```

Note that you must include the unit parameter, and it must be set to days ('D').

#### Edit 2020-06-27

In response to [Sami Navesi's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48587595/convert-julian-dates-to-normal-dates-in-a-dataframe/59097445?noredirect=1#comment110694667_59097445), if the `DATA_BLOCK_CODE_1` column is integer or string, you can split the year out (convert to string) and convert the julian days separately [as shown in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38067348/creating-datetime-in-pandas-from-year-and-julian-day).  This example assumes the `DATA_BLOCK_CODE_1` is string.  The results are the same as above.

`amna['Date'] = [pd.to_datetime(e[:4]) + pd.to_timedelta(int(e[4:]) - 1, unit='D') for e in amna['DATA_BLOCK_CODE_1']]`

Comment: it throws an error: incompatible 'arg' type for given 'origin'='julian'!

Answer (score 0):

```java
df.createOrReplaceTempView("df")

new_df =  sprak.sql("select *, from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(cast(DATA_BLOCK_CODE_1as string),'yyyyDDD'),'yyyy-MM-dd') from df")

new_df.show()
```