# Can Pandas's `to_datetime` parse BCE dates?

Tags: pandas

Given a date like 8300 BCE, I run `pd.to_datetime("-8300", format="%y")`.

This produces `ValueError: time data '-8300' does not match format '%y' (match)`.

Is there a way to handle "negative" dates in Pandas?

Answer (score 0):

Yes,

I hope this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48587595/convert-julian-dates-to-normal-dates-in-a-dataframe) helps.

There is a procedure given in documentation for Julian dates, you can find that [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html). Focus on `unit` & `origin` arguments

Comment: Can you provide an example? `pd.to_datetime("1970", unit="D", origin="julian")` produces `ValueError: incompatible 'arg' type for given 'origin'='julian'`. If I make 1970 an int rather than str, I get `OutOfBoundsDatetime`.